# Modified picture based on three different sources - citations needed?

Tags: citations, graphics

I am thinking about where the borderline is with citations. 
I made a new picture based on three different sources, so I wrote under the picture "adapted from [3,6,9]." This, however, seems to be funny.

When do you need to include citations for your modifications of pictures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your first instinct is correct, it just needs a little bit of clarification in wording.  I would suggest something like:

> Created by combining adaptations of Figure X from [3], Figure Y from [6], and Figure Z from [9].

Comment: how would you do this in APA style? Using commas or semicolons?

Such as: (own illustration based on source A; source B; source C)

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what kind of information you are adapting from original pictures.

If original picture has some very well accepted content in field which you are adapting, you can modify it and use it in your figure. In that case you don't need to give citations. For example, if you are using symbols used in original figures which are well accepted in field, you can use without citing original source.

In contrast, if picture has some new content or some unique concept which you are adapting then you should acknowledge it. For example, if original figure is showing some unique symbol which is output of their new research or imagination, then you should acknowledge it.

However it is always **best practice to cite all** images from which you have adapted content.

Answer (score 2):

> When do you need to include citations for your modifications of pictures?

## ALWAYS.

Any time you modify somebody else's work, you **must** cite them.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain in what circumstances they feel that it's appropriate to modify somebody's work without citing them?